# How can I stream my desktop via Ustream?

Tags: video, streaming

I'm looking to stream my desktop live via a service such as ustream and having extreme difficulty in finding a solution.

I've tried WebcamStudio and it could only use FME files which don't work with Ustream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steps:

1. Install webcam studio ( http://sourceforge.net/projects/webcamstudio/files/ )
2. start `webcamstudio`
3. click `Sources` => `Desktop`
4. click the Play icon
5. you can checkout a preview with the `Show Preview` button
6. login to ustream and click start broadcast
7. in the flash input dialog choose `webcamstudio`

credits go to: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9517840&postcount=16

edit: Testet this at lucid and it is working.

Comment: The latest version of WCS doesn't work. It's deprecated. :(